# Matplotlib scatter(): default value for size, marker shape

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to set **default** marker size (`s`) parameter for matplotlib `plt.scatter()` (or likewise to set the shape of the marker)?

`mpl.rcParams.keys()` has settings for the line plots, e.g.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['lines.marker']='D'
```

... but they do not seem to relate to `plt.scatter()`.

Thanks.

**Clarification:**

I'd like to use a configuration mechanism like `mpl.rcParams()`, or some other reasonably civilized method. Locally modifying library code is not it.

On the other hand, if it cannot currently be done and somebody submits a patch to Matplotlib, that would be awesome.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is currently configurable.

Comment: @tcaswell - That would seem like a strange omission, but it's certainly possible. I'll open a feature request issue with mpl unless somebody comes up with an answer in a couple days.

Comment: There are lots of strange omissions.  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/rcsetup.py#L760 <- that is the canonical list of things that can be configured via rcparams.

Comment: As of a fix pushed in March 2016, the default size of markers for scatter plots can be set - it is based on rcParams['lines.markersize'], see the commit: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/13edbb52bfe804a815c0c49d56137f64ee3e7d7a. Since that's the latest commit to that file, most likely there is still no way to set the default marker shape for scatter plots though (the default appears to be hardcoded as 'o').

Answer (score 6):

Of course there is, it's all in the [pyplot.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/0037595096e3be3ec863f3e3008e73c469e2f2b8/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L3238)

A snippet from their code:

```
def scatter(x, y, s=20, c=None, marker='o', cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None,
            vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, verts=None, edgecolors=None,
            hold=None, data=None, **kwargs):
```

The size is set to 20 `s=20` and the marker shape is a circle `marker='o'` which agrees with their documentation

Comment: ... not sure how this helps. My question is about setting **default** size; not about doing it in a particular invocation of scatter()

Comment: This is not a particular invocation, that *is* the default size. If you change that `s` value in there it'll change across *all* `plt.scatter()`

Comment: The question stated "Locally modifying library code is not it" and I guess that's what you suggest, @Leb, right?

Answer (score 6):

In the current release, marker size is defined as:

"The marker size in points**2. Default is rcParams['lines.markersize'] ** 2."

So setting rcParams['lines.markersize'] should change the default marker size for scatterplots too now. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

Comment: ty! plt.scatter indeed respects changes made to defaults, e.g., `plt.rcParams['lines.markersize'] = 1.25`. Also, see https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html for more info :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the current release of matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

However, there is an option to change the default marker in the master branch on GitHub (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/rcsetup.py#L1112).