# Changing default edge-color for matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to change the *default* edge color for matplotlib scatter plots. Typically, things like that would be set through `rcParams`, and my understanding is that I should set `patch.edgecolor`. However, that doesn't seem to work. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(50)
y = np.random.randn(50)

with plt.rc_context({'patch.edgecolor': 'white'}):
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.scatter(x, y, edgecolors='white')
```

In the result, I would like to have both subplots look the same, but instead they look like this:
[image: What I want to see]
Note that I don't want to change the code within the `with` statement, but instead configure matplotlib such that it uses white edges as a fallback if I don't specify anything else. Confusingly, the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) uses a default argument `edgecolors=None` in the function signature, but states that the default value for `edgecolors` is `'face'`. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: As of now there seems to be no such possibility. Read the comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935914/matplotlib-scatter-default-value-for-size-marker-shape). Currently the attributes for markers which you can set by default are `plt.rcParams["lines.markeredgewidth"] = 2`, `plt.rcParams["lines.markersize"] = 10`, and `plt.rcParams["scatter.marker"] = 'o'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rc parameter you're looking for is called

```
'scatter.edgecolors'
```

E.g.  `plt.rcParams['scatter.edgecolors'] = "white"`
or
`with plt.rc_context({'scatter.edgecolors': 'white'}):`.

This is a new feature introduced in [#12992](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12992) and available from **matplotlib 3.1** onwards, which will be released very soon. As of today, you can install the release candidate via `pip install --pre --upgrade matplotlib` to get this feature.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere else than in the PR?

Comment: Well, since it's not yet officially released, it's only in the [devdocs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html), where it says about edgecolors *Defaults to None, in which case it takes the value of `rcParams["scatter.edgecolors"] = 'face'`.*